# The report has no tables in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-2008

I am designing a windows based application in VB.NET 2008 using an MS Access .mdb file.
Below is my code; the issue I face is that the report has no tables. I have no typed dataset.
I am directly populating reports with the below query:

```
Imports System.Data Imports System.Data.OleDb 
Public Class  frmInvoiceReport
        Public da As OleDbDataAdapter
        Public ds As DataSet
        Public con As OleDbConnection
        Public cmd As OleDbCommand
        Public dt As DataTable
        Public sBuilder As OleDbCommandBuilder
        Public sqlq, constr, table As String
        Private Sub frmInvoiceReport_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            constr = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath &
    "\Shri_Swami_Samartha_Classes.mdb")
            con = New OleDbConnection(constr)
            con.Open()
            sqlq = "Select * from InvoiceRptQuery where SerialCode =1"
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then con.Close()
            con.Open()
            da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlq, con)
            ds = New DataSet
            da.Fill(ds)
            con.Close()
            Dim obj As New Mrptv1
            obj.SetDataSource(ds.Tables("InvoiceRptQuery"))
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = obj
            CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
        End Sub
 End Class
```

Comment: You are trying to create the table? Or just show it?

Comment: Hi Chase, I am trying to load my crystalreport with the help of my select query. But I am facing Report has no table Error.

Comment: Well, I found answer for this problem. I had to add Datable in datasource.fill(). I had to do changes as : -  da.Fill(ds1, "dtable1") and obj.SetDataSource(ds1). ds1 is a typed datasource and dtable1 is the datatable added in it.

Comment: can you give me your sample code? I am facing the same problems, thanks :)